# 通知センター/コントロールセンター表示時のapplication:didReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

LocalNotificationによるプッシュ通知から、アプリの特定画面にダイレクトに
遷移する機能を持つiOSアプリを開発しています。通知センターの通知をタップ
した際の画面遷移はフォアグラウンド時/バックグラウンド時共に実現できているの
ですが、コントロールセンターや通知センターを表示しているときに通知が実施
されると通知センターの通知をタップしたのと同様に遷移が実施されてしまいます。

条件の振り分けとしてapplicationStateのプロパティの値を評価し、アプリを通常
使用している際（UIApplicationStateActive）は遷移が行われないようにしているの
ですが、通知センターやコントロールセンターが表示されている場合は通知をタップ
した場合と同様のUIApplicationStateInactiveで返ってきます。そのため通知を
タップしたのと同じ遷移が発生しているのですが、別の方法でコントロールセンターや
通知センターが表示されているだけの状態と、通知をタップしたときの状態を振り分け
できないでしょうか。

アプリ対応OSをiOS 7以降としているため、iOS 8からのNotification Actionが使えない状況です。

回答頂いた部分を含めて、実現したいことと試したことは以下の通りです。

**実現したいこと**
・通知受信時にユーザーの操作なしにアプリの画面遷移は行わない
（通知センター/コントロールセンター表示時を含む）
・通知をタップした際はアプリがフォアグラウンド/バックグラウンド時
　共にアプリ内特定画面に遷移する

**試したこと**
・didReceiveLocalNotification内でapplicationStateの値で処理を振り分け
　→通知センター/コントロールセンター表示時に操作せず遷移する以外は仕様通りに動作
・ライフサイクルの確認
　→通知センター/コントロールセンター表示時の通知受信と、通知センターの
　　通知タップ時はどちらもapplicationWillResignActive・didReceiveLocalNotification・
　　applicationDidBecomeActiveの順番でAppDelegate内のメソッドが呼ばれているので
　　どちらの経路から来ているか判定できない
・applicationStateを各ライフサイクル時にキャッシュしてdidReceiveLocalNotification内で判定
　→通知センター/コントロールセンター表示時の通知受信で勝手に遷移はしなくなるものの、
　　通知をタップした際にも遷移しなくなる

本家SOでも同様の質問がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232997/receiving-remote-notification-right-when-the-app-is-activating
回答がつかないところを見ると実現が難しいのでしょうか。

Comment: 消極的な対策のような気はしますが、ライフサイクル状態を保持しておいて、通知センターやコントロールセンター表示時はapplicationWillResignActiveにいるので、その情報を元にdidReceiveLocalNotficationが呼ばれる際にガードすることにしました。チェックはディレイを入れて通知タップ時は通知センターが消えapplicationDidBecomeActiveにいるため、それでタップされたことを判定しました。通知が来てガードされる前に通知センターやコントロールセンターを表示→非表示にするとタップされたと見なして通ってしまいますが、何もしないよりはマシかなと。引き続き考えてみます。